# PayPal - Magento failing to update order status to "Closed" after full refund

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status, paypal-express

Just recently, order statuses for fully refunded orders will fail to update to "Closed" after refund processing. This is for PayPal Express / Standard.

After the "Processing" status, instead of going to "Closed", it goes back to "Complete".

[image]

It's hard to narrow down the actual day it began happening, but from what I can tell, it was around the time I issued my first refund for my second store. I have two stores that use the same IPN notification URL, and I'm unsure if this is the reason. Both stores are under the same domain, however the second one is a subdomain. The first one (the one under the main domain) is the one having the issue.

I'm not getting any warnings/errors being sent from PayPal.

I haven't added any new code that would interfere with anything order-related, nor have I added any new plugins. This is more of a nuisance than anything else, so if anybody has any ideas what could cause this or a possible fix, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar issue in Magento in 2.1.7. The problem was caused due to a bug. It was fixed through 2.2.0 update. So, I think that using the latest and the most stable version of Magento will fix your issue, as you are not getting any error from PayPal.

Comment: I'm currently using 1.9.4, but I'm beginning the process of upgrading to Magento 2, so I assume it will disappear after the upgrade.